# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Смонтировать фланцы на трубопроводах", или их нужно установить?

Answer (score 1):

Это технический сленг, тут вряд ли можно что-то рекомендовать помимо использования уже сложившихся оборотов. Если так говорят профессионалы, значит можно.